# which one is a better way to create html elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

Which is the more professional way. I like the first one better because you can pass in the `class`, `id`, `name` etc in one line.

1)

```
var button = "<button type='button' id='mybutton'></button>";
document.body.innerHTML+= button;
```

2)

```
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: The second, it's the only one which works.

Comment: sorry editted the firs one. how about now?

Comment: They're just different, there's not one that's "more professional". When you need a highly degree of control you need to manipulate nodes individually, when you just want to insert large hunks of HTML then `innerHTML` performs better.

Comment: This question is either too broad or primarily opinion based. There are a lot of factors in choosing one method over the other.

Comment: Get more detail here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: Now the first will re-create and override all existing HTML in `body`, which definitely is not preferred.

Comment: And first will also disturb the DOM tree and events attached to those elements using JS event binding..